# Spring Batch remote-partitioning with Kafka - master always continues the oldest job in the JobListener

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I'm using `spring-batch` along with `spring-boot 2.5.6`. I decided to use remote-partitioning with Kafka as the middleware. I have one manager and three workers. accordingly, one partition has been assigned for the manager's input topic and three partitions have been assigned for the worker's input.

the manager takes a file, creates multiples `ExecutionContext`s and sends those over Kafka. workers start processing the respective steps and send the message at the end of their process. manager will aggregate the worker's results and decide to complete the job if all workers are done. so far so good.

now assume first I run a long-running job that requires lots of time to finish and then I run a small job that finishes quickly. not surprisingly the second job finishes sooner and sends a completed signal, the manager consumes this message and continues the process. I even checked `AggregatingMessageHandler`, the completed message is related to the second job  (short-running one) only, I checked the `jobExecutionId`

now the problem happens, I have a `JobListener` that has an `afterJob` method. this method will be run against the first job (the long-running one that is still being processed by workers), not the second one (the short-running one that a completed signal has been sent for it)! I can say this by looking at the `jobExecutionId`. it's really weird because I never saw in the logs that there's a completion signal for the first job.

after some time and whenever the first long-running job is finished, the final worker sends a completed message and the manager decides to finish the job, now the `JobListener` is run against the second job (short-running one)!

I couldn't understand what goes wrong? I would like to assume that probably it's a miss-configuration, but by debugging the code and checking `AggregatingMessageHandler` and TRACE logs in the workers and manager, I can clearly see that the messages are being sent fine and there's nothing wrong with the messages. any suggestions/ideas are welcome.

**UPDATE**

here is a sample implementation: let's say we have a Customer table.
the job takes `minId` and `maxId` (ID column in Customer table is a simple number) then the manager creates multiple ExecutionContexts based on the ids range.

manager config

```
package com.example.batchdemo.job;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.Partitioner;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.RemotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.kafka.dsl.Kafka;
import org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollerMetadata;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConsumerProperties;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger;

@Profile("!worker")
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration {

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final JobExplorer jobExplorer;
    private final RemotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory managerStepBuilderFactory;
    private final JobListener jobListener;

    public JobConfiguration(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, JobExplorer jobExplorer, RemotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory managerStepBuilderFactory, JobListener jobListener) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.jobExplorer = jobExplorer;
        this.managerStepBuilderFactory = managerStepBuilderFactory;
        this.jobListener = jobListener;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(managerStep())
                .listener(jobListener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step managerStep() {
        return managerStepBuilderFactory.get("managerStep")
                .partitioner("workerStep", rangePartitioner(null, null))
                .outputChannel(requestForWorkers())
                .inputChannel(repliesFromWorkers())
                .jobExplorer(jobExplorer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Partitioner rangePartitioner(@Value("#{jobParameters['minId']}") Integer minId, @Value("#{jobParameters['maxId']}") Integer maxId) {
        return new CustomerIdRangePartitioner(minId, maxId);
    }


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requestForWorkers() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(requestForWorkers())
                .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).topic("requestForWorkers"))
                .route("requestForWorkers")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel repliesFromWorkers() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(ConsumerFactory consumerFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Kafka.inboundChannelAdapter(consumerFactory, new ConsumerProperties("repliesFromWorkers")))
                .channel(repliesFromWorkers())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(10));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }

}
```

worker config

```
package com.example.batchdemo.job;

import com.example.batchdemo.domain.Customer;
import com.example.batchdemo.domain.CustomerRowMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.SimpleStepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.RemotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.Order;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.MySqlPagingQueryProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.kafka.dsl.Kafka;
import org.springframework.integration.scheduling.PollerMetadata;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConsumerProperties;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@Profile("worker")
public class WorkerConfiguration {

    private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int WAITING_TIME = 3000;

    public final DataSource dataSource;
    private final RemotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory workerStepBuilderFactory;

    public WorkerConfiguration(DataSource dataSource, RemotePartitioningWorkerStepBuilderFactory workerStepBuilderFactory) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.workerStepBuilderFactory = workerStepBuilderFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel repliesFromWorkers() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(repliesFromWorkers())
                .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).topic("repliesFromWorkers"))
                .route("repliesFromWorkers")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requestForWorkers() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(ConsumerFactory consumerFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Kafka.inboundChannelAdapter(consumerFactory, new ConsumerProperties("requestForWorkers")))
                .channel(requestForWorkers())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(10));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Bean
    public Step workerStep() {
        SimpleStepBuilder workerStepBuilder = workerStepBuilderFactory.get("workerStep")
                .inputChannel(requestForWorkers())
                .outputChannel(repliesFromWorkers())
                .<Customer, Customer>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
                .reader(pagingItemReader(null, null))
                .processor(itemProcessor())
                .writer(customerItemWriter());
        return workerStepBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcPagingItemReader<Customer> pagingItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['minValue']}") Long minValue,
                                                           @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['maxValue']}") Long maxValue) {
        System.out.println("reading " + minValue + " to " + maxValue);
        JdbcPagingItemReader<Customer> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();

        reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        reader.setFetchSize(1000);
        reader.setRowMapper(new CustomerRowMapper());

        MySqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider();
        queryProvider.setSelectClause("id, firstName, lastName, birthdate");
        queryProvider.setFromClause("from CUSTOMER");
        queryProvider.setWhereClause("where id >= " + minValue + " and id < " + maxValue);

        Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>(1);

        sortKeys.put("id", Order.ASCENDING);

        queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

        reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);

        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemProcessor<Customer, Customer> itemProcessor() {
        return item -> {
            Thread.sleep(WAITING_TIME);
            System.out.println(item);
            return item;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<Customer> customerItemWriter() {
        return items -> {
            System.out.printf("%d items were written%n", items.size());
        };
    }

}
```

Partitioner:

```
package com.example.batchdemo.job;

import org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.Partitioner;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomerIdRangePartitioner implements Partitioner {

    private final int minId;
    private final int maxId;
    private final int gridSize;

    public CustomerIdRangePartitioner(int minId, int maxId, int gridSize) {
        this.minId = minId;
        this.maxId = maxId;
        this.gridSize = gridSize;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        int number = (maxId - minId) / this.gridSize + 1;

        Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
            int start = minId + (this.gridSize * i);
            int end = start + (this.gridSize * (i + 1));
            executionContext.putInt("minValue", start);
            executionContext.putInt("maxValue", Math.min(end, maxId));
            result.put("partition" + i, executionContext);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

JobListener

```
package com.example.batchdemo.job;

import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobScope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@JobScope
public class JobListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        System.out.println(jobExecution.getJobId() + " was finished: " + jobExecution.getStatus());
    }

}
```

AppConfiguration

```
package com.example.batchdemo.controller;

import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobRegistry;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.core.converter.DefaultJobParametersConverter;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    private final JobExplorer jobExplorer;
    private final JobRepository jobRepository;
    private final JobRegistry jobRegistry;
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public AppConfiguration(JobExplorer jobExplorer, JobRepository jobRepository, JobRegistry jobRegistry, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.jobExplorer = jobExplorer;
        this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
        this.jobRegistry = jobRegistry;
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public synchronized JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistrar() throws Exception {
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor registrar = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();

        registrar.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        registrar.setBeanFactory(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
        registrar.afterPropertiesSet();

        return registrar;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobOperator jobOperator() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobOperator simpleJobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();

        simpleJobOperator.setJobLauncher(getJobLauncher());
        simpleJobOperator.setJobParametersConverter(new DefaultJobParametersConverter());
        simpleJobOperator.setJobRepository(this.jobRepository);
        simpleJobOperator.setJobExplorer(this.jobExplorer);
        simpleJobOperator.setJobRegistry(this.jobRegistry);

        simpleJobOperator.afterPropertiesSet();

        return simpleJobOperator;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = null;
        jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(jobOperatorExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor jobOperatorExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(64);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(256);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>batch-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>batch-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is impossible to tell you what is wrong. You seem to be sharing beans between different jobs. Try to use distinct bean instances (reader, writer, listener, etc) for each job in separate configurations (or make them step/job scoped) and make each job instance process a distinct file (ie the file is an identifying job parameter). With this, you can run as many job instances as your resources allow to without any issue.

Comment: As mentioned on [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4133), I will debug your case based on your MCE and get back to you here with an answer or a request for more details.

Comment: Hi. When trying the sample you shared, the command to create topics `kafka-topics --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:22181 ...` seems incorrect as the zookeeper port (`22181`) is not the same as the one exposed in docker compose (`ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181`). I guess this is a typo. I tried to fix it by using the same port but I'm still having an issue while creating the topics: `$> kafka-topics --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --topic requestForWorkers --create --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1

Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: zookeeper is not a recognized option`

Comment: hi. if you have used the same docker-compose in the github, 22181 has been exposed for the zookeeper. please try using this command: `kafka-topics --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:29092 --topic requestForWorkers --create --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1` also if you're not using Windows, probably you need to run `kafka-topics.sh` instead of `kafka-topics`

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I came to the same conclusion as well before seeing your comment (the `--zookeeper` option is deprecated in favor of `--bootstrap-server`). I am now able to run your sample and debug the case. I will try to get back to you asap with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Spring Batch. The listener is indeed called for the job that finishes earlier with the wrong `JobExecution` instance. Making the `JobExecutionListener` job-scoped does not solve the issue.

I will re-open the [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4133) on Github for further investigation.

Comment: glad to hear you found it! we're waiting for the fix!