Remote Partitioning in Spring Batch - Job completion for small number of records can't de done until Job completes for large number of records
I am trying Spring Batch with remote partitioning [ master-salve approach].
I have one master step which sends records to worker nodes via KAFKA.
All was working fine until parallel job executions made
Scenario:
I launched a job with 50k records and the records are sent to worker nodes for processing and around the same time i launched a another job with only 100 records where the same worker nodes listen to kafka topics for records
I saw that the the worker nodes first takes records of 50k records and process it and next takes 100 records of another job,
Do a job with 100 records should really wait for a job with 50K records to process?
Adding a taskExecutor in processor making it async is possible to make the processor as fast the threads assigned but the concern is about the waiting of 100 records job

Seems like messages from different jobs are mixed in the channels. Are you running these two jobs in the same JVM? In this case, you need to make the message channel writer step-scoped, see answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332048/spring-batch-how-to-configure-remote-chunking-for-multiple-jobs-running-in-a-t

Yeah I am running the two jobs in the same JVM. I saw the worker step timings the problem is while at the starting of worker step. ( When the partitions data assigned to workers they start processing but other partition offset within the same partition of topic will in queue until the processing being completed of the previous partition offset)

Sorry' i didn't get the point of writer channel being step scoped as since the worker step not able to start processing the data of next partition offset


Yeah I am running the two jobs in the same JVM.

I would not recommend this in general, and even less in the partitioning case. The reason is that it is impossible to scale these jobs independently.
If you are using the MessageChannelPartitionHandler, then you need to make it step-scoped to avoid message crossing. There is note about this in its javadocs:
The reply channel for this is instance based. Sharing this component across
multiple step instances may result in the crossing of messages. It's
recommended that this component be step or job scoped.


Sorry, I am using RemotePartitioningManagerStepBuilderFactory provided by the framework. Is there anything to do with it?

It is not possible to specify a custom scope of the MessageChannelPartitionHandler when using the builder. You need to setup that handler manually and declare it as a step-scoped bean.

Since we have filters as end-point in spring integration, can't we add a filter as end-point for the messages that needs to be consumed to solve crossing of messages ?
just a thought, sorry if it was silly question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72601168/spring-batch-remote-partitioning-with-kafka-master-always-continues-the-oldest/79308790#79308790
I guess filters can be added to solve this question
